# Slutsky's Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

In [Slutsky's Theorem's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem) proof as outlined in the link, we can get the general results that $g(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow_d g(X,c)$ whenever $g$ is continuous. However, in the Continuous Mapping Theorem, it said nothing about $g$ having to be continuous. My question is: Is it still true if I replace the condition of continuous with Borel measurable?

Comment: **hint:** the name of the theorem is *continuous* mapping theorem.

Comment: But in the statement of it, it says nothing about continuous, as long as the measure of the set of discontinuous points is 0.

Comment: They are using the Heine Definition of continuity, which is limit preserving, as opposed to the more restricted calculus definition of continuity.